# Chutzpah stop on first failed test

Tags: unit-testing, qunit, chutzpah

I am currently Chutzpah with Visual Studio .NET 2013 and QUnit.  My chutzpah.json settings file has all of the JavaScript unit tests listed in a very specific order.  However each test is dependent on the prior one succeeding, therefore, if one unit test fails, all of the others after it will fail also.

Is there a way to tell Chutzpah to stop testing as soon as it encounters the first failed test?  I know that there is a setting in Visual Studio .NET built-in unit testing for this but it doesn't have any affect in Chutzpah.

Thanks in advance for your answers/suggestions.

Comment: Your unit tests shouldn't be structured to rely on a certain order to be run in, this makes them incredibly fragile and a pain to maintain. If you give me a bit more info maybe I can help with it, what are the tests relying on ?

To answer your question, I don't think there is a way of stopping it bar modifying Chutzpah yourself. Chutzpah is active on GitHub: https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah

Comment: Chutzpah doesn't have a way to stop after first failed. The idea is all tests should be able to be run in isolation and they should not depend on eachother.

Comment: If that is true then why does Visual Studio .NET 2013 have an option for its native unit tests?